# Para que serve o comando xargs?

Tags: linux, bash

Para que serve o comando `xargs`?

Por exemplo, já vi exemplos

```
 ls pasta/ | xargs -l git update-index
```

Eu vi que isso estava sendo usado porque o comando `git update-index` não funciona com pastas.

Mas, na prática, não sei para que serve esse comando.

Comment: Galera que ta negativando, seria interessante apontar para o autor o que torna a pergunta merecedora de tantos negativos, assim você colabora com a qualidade do site e com o aprendizado do OP.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A função primordial é construir listas de parâmetros e passá-la para a execução de outros programas ou instruções. Este comando deve ser usado da seguinte maneira:

```
xargs [comando [argumento inicial]]
```

Caso o comando, que pode ser inclusive um script Shell, seja omitido, será usado por default o echo.

O `xargs` combina o argumento inicial com os argumentos recebidos da entrada padrão, de forma a executar o comando especificado uma ou mais vezes.

Exemplo:

Vamos procurar em todos os arquivos abaixo de um determinado diretório uma cadeia de caracteres usando o comando find com a opção type f para pesquisar somente os arquivos normais, desprezando diretórios, arquivos especiais, arquivos de ligações, etc, e vamos torná-la mais genérica recebendo o nome do diretório inicial e a cadeia a ser pesquisada como parâmetros. Para isso fazemos:

```
$ cat grepr
  #
  # Grep recursivo
  # Pesquisa a cadeia de caracteres definida em $2 a partir do diretorio $1
  #
  find $1 -type f -print|xargs grep -l "$2"
```

Na execução deste script procuramos, a partir do diretório definido na variável $1, todos os arquivos que continham a cadeia definida na variável $2.

Exatamente a mesma coisa poderia ser feito se a linha do programa fosse a seguinte:

```
find $1 -type f -exec grep -l "$2" {} \;
```

Este processo tem duas grandes desvantagens sobre o anterior:

1. A primeira é bastante visível: o tempo de execução deste método é
   muito superior ao daquele, isso porque o grep será feito em cada
   arquivo que lhe for passado pelo find, um-a-um, ao passo que com o
   xargs, será passada toda, ou na pior das hipóteses, a maior parte
   possível, da lista de arquivos gerada pelo find;
2. Dependendo da quantidade de arquivos encontrados que atendem ao
   find, poderemos ganhar aquela famosa e fatídica mensagem de erro
   "Too many arguments" indicando um estouro da pilha de execução do
   grep. Como foi dito no item anterior, se usarmos o xargs ele passará
   para o grep a maior quantidade de parâmetros possível, suficiente
   para não causar este erro, e caso necessário executará o grep mais
   de uma vez.

ATENÇÃO! Aê pessoal do linux que usa o `ls` colorido que nem porta de tinturaria: nos exemplos a seguir que envolvem esta instrução, você devem usar a opção `--color=none`, senão existem grandes chances dos resultados não ocorrerem como o esperado.

Vamos agora analisar um exemplo que é mais ou menos o inverso deste que acabamos de ver. Desta vez, vamos fazer um script para remover todos os arquivos do diretório corrente, pertencentes a um determinado usuário.

A primeira idéia que surge é, como no caso anterior, usar um comando find, da seguinte maneira:

```
$ find . -user cara -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Quase estaria certo, o problema é que desta forma você removeria não só os arquivos do cara no diretório corrente, mas também de todos os outros subdiretórios "pendurados" neste. Vejamos então como fazer:

```
$ ls -l | grep " cara " | cut -c55- | xargs rm
```

Desta forma, o grep selecionou os arquivos que continham a cadeia cara no diretório corrente listado pelo ls -l. O comando cut pegou somente o nome dos arquivos, passando-os para a remoção pelo rm usando o comando xargs como ponte.

[Fonte](http://www.dicas-l.com.br/cantinhodoshell/cantinhodoshell_20070226.php)